# What good are psychics who control the strong or weak forces?

Tags: magic, super-powers, psionics, strong-force, weak-force

So I have a modern setting with psions.  Their powers fall into groups that control different well defined things, with many controlling fundamental forces. The psions' powers automatically attempt to protect them from known threats so someone who manipulates kinetic energy would be able to stop bullets easily.  Similarly electromagnetic control would stop bullets in many different ways (for instance vaporize it with a laser in midair).

- However this power system sticks some unlucky people with control over the strong or weak force. *Psychics have limits over how much energy they can generate* **so someone couldn't just disassemble an entire object with the strong force, because of how much bond energy would be released or taken, in fact pretty much any use of these forces on the macroscopic scale has the same problems.** Given the short range of both these forces it seems to me that a psion wouldn't be able to to do much more, than bathe the area with radiation with either of these powers.  I'm not even sure a psychic could use this power to protect themselves from that radiation either. Psions can for the most part only influence areas they can see, and can't do stuff to the interior of an object but not the exterior, since they can't see it.
- **So what exactly could someone do with one of these powers?** Applications that would be actually be likely to come up in a RPG or story are more preferable than extremely niche uses. Power is limited by sight range, so *maybe* the psion could avoid radiation.  But still compared to what other powers can do, these don't seem that great (hell, several other powers like EM control can also release radiation like this).

So what is a weak-force, or strong-force psychic to do? In addition, is there a way to use either of these powers to protect yourself from the radiation produced by the powers themselves, or anything else for that matter?

Comment: are they limited to control the forces from themselves or can do it from a distance? and generally asking for a list of magic powers tends to be too broad a question

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin They can influence anything they can see, which is a pretty typical limitation for superpowers in fiction.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Also I don't really think a list of abilities would be to broad, after all as stated in the question, I don't actually think you can do very much controlling the strong and weak forces, thus such a list wouldn't be very long. If there are other uses for these abilities I want to know.

Comment: Ok I edited the question to be somewhat more clear, I'm not sure what exactly the problems were in the first place but I hope this resolves it.

Comment: Requesting reopen as it seems pretty clear the question now.  See here:  https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/reopen-request-what-good-are-psychics

Comment: The weak and strong force both have very small range so they can only active when touching I guess. Weak force users would be able to explode themselves in a nuclear explosion by making all their atoms unstable and strong users can explode themselves in a even bigger explosion by making all their protons and neutrons unstable.

Answer (score 3):

Your strong force psychics are also bullet proof.  They simply cause the bullets to bond with the air that they pass through until the accumulated mass of the bullet overwhelms its velocity.

I don't think we have a scientific term for an object slowing down as its mass grows, but assuming that the kinetic inspiration from the gun powder is constant or diminishing through the bullet's flight, then if the bullet's mass suddenly doubled, wouldn't its velocity be shared across that mass, reducing the bullet's speed?

Theoretically, if the strong force psychic had adequate control of their power, they could literally create a solid object out of the particles of the air molecules ahead of the bullet; creating an obstacle to deflect the bullet.  DC's Green Lantern can be thought of as a strong force psychic with a little kinetic psychic skill thrown in, since he can move the objects he creates.

Aggressively, the force psychic could negate the bonds within a few atoms in the gunman's brain while reinforcing the bonds in those atoms surrounding the resulting spontaneous nuclear decay.  The result would not be a nuclear chain reaction, but rather a single burst of intense heat and radiation.  If properly regulated, there would be enough heat to cook the gunman's brain inside its skull, but not enough radiation to escape through the bone (except as a cool glow effect pouring from the victim's eye sockets).

In the Psychic Corps, weak force psychics are called "bullet bags" because they are the only ones who aren't immune to bullets.  They are however insanely powerful offensive weapons, so it is not unusual to have multiple non-weak force psychics assigned as guards for talented weak force psychic.

The value of the weak force psychic comes from their ability to make objects radioactive ...subtlely.  There is no nuclear explosion like when a strong force psychic goes suicidal, just an invisible glow as the enemy's weapons become tools of their own distruction.  Weak force psychics are the terrorists of the psychic wars.  They are the warriors who haunt the enemy leaders with nightmares.

Comment: First off how much energy would you need to cause metal atoms to spontaneously bond with the air atoms, because to have a significant effect it would almost certainly exceed the powers energy limits. I'm not sure what you're talking about when it comes to the gunpowder stuff, what bonding strength? How does the strong force relate to to chemical energy of the gunpowder? As for the radiation example, I can see using radiation to cook people's brains, but what exactly do you mean by strengthening the bonds of the surrounding atoms in their brain, what would that achieve?

Comment: @Vakus Drake, First off, the OP didn't provide any energy limits and actually implied that energy limits don't apply since his electromagnetic psychics can vaporize bullets.  How much energy is needed to sublimate lead?   On the effects of modified chemical effects caused by subatomic restructuring, I will back off on that front.  Science has made no allowances for any psychic abilities, so any time we try to discuss them, we have to mess with the current science.  But I have lost this battle before on other questions, so I will delete that part of my answer.

Comment: @VakusDrake, Thanks to your feedback, I have rethought who would have control over the combustability of gun powder.  It would be the electromagnetic psychic who could change things chemically.  We tend to think of electromagnetics as lightning and magnets, but when discussing the atomic forces, it is electromagnetics which determines which chemicals react with others.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how much energy would be needed to render a bullet ineffective so I may need to rework that example if I find out the energy level is *really* high. Even with vaporizing bullets levels of energy, I think the amount of energy required to overcome the strong force is *massive*. So I'm not sure there is any way to affect the bonds of macroscopic amounts of atoms without releasing insane amounts of energy *on par with small nuclear detonations*, I'm not kidding fusion is more energetic than fission.

Comment: Also as for it being a psychic ability: Well stuff about this question can be generalized, for anything in a story that controls those forces, in a variety of ways though combat is the best use I can think of.

Comment: I agree on the energy levels issue.  In several of my stories, the energy needed for psychic powers came from outside our universe and was not subject to its conservation of mass/energy laws.  Sort of like in Firestarter, where there was enough energy around to crack the planet if needed.  If you are working with more limited powersource, your Strong and Weak force psychics would be more defensive.  Maybe they could draw power from a nuclear power plant and use it to stablize the nuclear payloads of approaching ICBMs.

Comment: Stabilizing nuclear material wouldn't work because you can change the strength of the forces effects but you would have to physically *see* the icbm and then keep looking at it to keep it from being able to go off.  The energy limits for the power drawn from the other universe the power comes from are in theory unlimited, however in reality only the best psions could generate enough power to generate a explosion that could really destroy buildings, generally I find it less of a headache to stick to levels of destruction not totally beyond something a person could make themselves.